# Phonegap App Json XMLHttpRequest() ProgressEvent Error on Android SDK 28 Android 9 and some ipads

Tags: android, ajax, phonegap

I'm using Phonegap Build to create an app for Android and iOS.

The app uses ajax to request data from an API.Google requests that we target SDK 28.
The app works fine on all but Android 9 apps. On Android 9 there is an ajax Processevent Error. I'm not sure what the error is as the XMLHttpRequest error event listener doesnt give much away but from what I am reading other people having the same issue when targetting SDK 28.

I tried targetting SDK 26 and it works fine.

I am also having the same issue on an Ipad mini. I don't know if it's related yet.

I have added wheitelisting to the config, and included android:usesCleartextTraffic=true. I am also targetting phonegap-version cli-7.1.0

Is there anything else I can add to the config.xml to make it work?

Some of the potential fixes came from this url:
https://community.adobe.com/t5/phonegap/jquery-ajax-not-working-in-android-9/td-p/10242625

...but it's not making a diffrence for me.

Does anyone with Phonegap skills know how to fix this?

Comment: I've tried exportin using the 9.0.0 CLI too but the problem remains :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

iOS requires Https for all Ajax requests. I added an SSL and it works.